# Visual Studio/Python Comm Port Control

Tags: python, serial-port

I am running a Python program in Visual Studio. The program reads and writes to a Comm port. When I first run the program, communications are established correctly. When I attempt to run the program a second time, the program is unable to establish a connection to the same Comm port. Solution is to get out of Visual Studio and start over again.

Are there any Visual Studio or Python "Comm port restart/recycle/relinquish" commands? I am thinking the problem is, the first running of the program establishes a link, that the second running can't interrupt/hasn't disconnected.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not closing com port, but without seeing your code it's just a guess. If you are using pySerial API for example you can use `with` as described [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) which will open and close the com port every time:

```
>>> port = serial.Serial()
>>> port.port = '...'
>>> with port as s:
...     s.write(b'hello')
```